# Which way is more appropriate implementing authentication using JWT token for an SPA being xss and csrf attack proof?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, csrf, xss

I'm wondering what is the best way to implement authentication using jwt token mechanism for a react SPA and being fully stateless and xss and csrf attack proof.

After a long search I can't find a consensus on the question. I found multiple potential solutions:

1. The **synchronizer token pattern** that seems to fit perfectly on "traditional" server side rendered application but not so much for an SPA
2. The **double submit cookie pattern** that would fit for an SPA but seems not to be fully secure according OWASP (MITM attack as an exemple)
3. The **cookie to header** pattern and it's variation that seems to address all of our requirements
4. The **service worker pattern** that seems to kind of work but looks heavy / bloated to implement
5. The **bff** pattern that works but need an additional piece of software to be correctly implemented and so back again with the old good session
6. Using an **access token and a refresh token** intelligently in combination

(I voluntary omitted storing token in local / session storage because of xss attack)

Next compiling this data I went to the conclusion that the **cookie to header approach** and the **access + refresh token** are reasonable solutions to implement token based authentication.

1. Regarding the cookie to header approach I found a variation consisting in signing a random unique csrf token inside the jwt token himself. That one being send by the server as a secure, httpOnly cookie. The response header also includes the csrf token previously generated.

   That one will be extracted and set in a local storage. Future requests from the front to our back will include that cookie containing the jwt token (obviously) and the javascript will incorporate as a header our csrf token from the local storage.

   When the backend receive the request it will verify the csrf token from the header with the one which was incorporated in the jwt token. This way we should be protected from csrf / xss attack as only javascript from the same domain can set the header (csrf protection) and the cookie can only be read  by the server (xss protection).
2. Regarding the access + refresh token approach the server will return a refresh token (with a long valid period) as a secure and httpOnly cookie and an access token (with a short valid period) in the response at user login.

   Javascript will set the access token from the response **in memory** of our frontend (react state, variable, signal, whatever) ; doing this no xss or even csrf attack could be done (because of in memory you remember). All of our api will be secure verifying this access token sent in the header. Except one route: the one responsible in refreshing tokens.

   On access token expiration we request the refresh endpoint that will verify the refresh token from the cookie. If the refresh token is valid it will return a new access token that will replace the previous one in memory.

   Here we have an api secure by the access token (protected from xss and csrf attack) and one endpoint dedicated to renew the access token. Even though a csrf attack is operated only the refresh endpoint could be called then simply returning a new access token to the user being tricked by the attack.

Am I right ? At the end, which one of those two solutions is the most secure / is the most preferable ?

Thanks.